# I canceled debit card used for payments on iCloud. How do I add new debit card for auto pay?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I canceled  debit card to pay for iCloud. How do I add a new one?

Answer (score 5):

Open System Preferences

Click on Apple AD

Click on Manage > in Apple ID summary click on Manage payments

Log in...

Enter your new card info